# Entity Framework - Loading multiple data from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui, telerik

I have the reporting system based on few hundreds stored procedures which some of them very complex as a back end. On the front end it is VB ASP.Net and Component One for charting. I have a task to refresh the system as it is over 10 years old. 
I'm planing to use C# Asp.Net MVC 5 and EF6 code first and for the front end and keep existing stored procedures. I already find that using stored procedures not going to be easy if possible. I would like to load the data from the stored procedure to the datagrid and use it to create Kendo UI charts.

My question is: Is this a right solution? If not what would you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably if you already have the database you will be using a database-first approach? If so, there is no issue using stored procs with EF - http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I'dont want to use current tables, it must be a new system. I only want to use stored procedures do get data for charting. Doing in the way the example shows I will end up mapping few hundreds of sp. I need something more flexible and universal, where I use stored procedure as a variable to get data. Thanks

Comment: "I don't want to use current tables" - but wouldn't your existing SPs be specific to the existing tables?

Comment: Yes but this is only a raw machine data which need to be modified and populated by stored procedures before I can use it. So none of the tables can be used as an entity.